# Why is autoreorderpoint not available in SuiteQL?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suiteql

NetSuite shows in their [Analytics Browser](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/analytics/record/item.html) that `autoreorderpoint` is available in SuiteScript and in workbooks; however, a simple `select top 10 autoreorderpoint from item` query returns an error, and the field is not available when creating a dataset. Is anyone able to shed light on this discrepancy? Is the Analytics browser reliable?

Comment: Another example is `item.quantitybackordered`. I haven't found an explanation yet.